# Find an optimal n square size (same for each) to fit most part of rectangle container

Tags: algorithm, math, user-interface, resize, geometry

**Input**

Rectangle area width and height, so we could calculate rectangle aspect/proportions.

N is the number of squares that we want to resize using **the same size for each**.

**Output**

Find the optimal squares size that would fit most part of our container. For example

```
containerWidth = 200;
containerHeight = 100;
n = 8;
```

In this case squaresSize should be 50 to fit most of rectangle area.

**What i tried**

I already tried to calculate container math area and then divide it to the number of squares to get each square area by taking a square root. But this is the ideal square size, so it douesn't respect each square place relative to container rectangle.

**Real purpouse**

I trying to make scallable user interface, that would draw as much square objects in rectangle container as it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `S` be the size of each square (width and height). Then you want to solve the optimization problem

```
  maximize S
subject to floor(Width / S) * floor(Height / S) >= n
           S >= 0
```

The feasible region is a range `[0, S*]`, where `S*` is the optimal solution.

We know that `S * S * n <= Width * Height` for all feasible `S`; that is, `S <= sqrt(Width * Height / n)`.

So you can simply binary search the range `[0, sqrt(Width * Height / n)]` for the largest value of `S` for which `floor(Width / S) * floor(Height / S) >= n`.

Once you have the optimal `S*`, you will place your squares into the container in a grid with `floor(Width / S*)` columns and `floor(Height / S*)` rows.

Comment: Is this considerably different from my answer? :)

Comment: @MBo Your answer was backed by the right idea, but it wasn't explained fully *why* it worked. The inequality `(Width div a) * (Height div a) >= n` also wasn't 100% correct since it assumes integer sizes, in a way that didn't seem deliberate.

Answer (score 3):

You have to solve inequality (find max value of a)

```
(Width div a) * (Height div a) >= n
```

where div is integer division with truncation (8 div 3 = 2)

Result depends monotonically on n, so get first approximation as

```
a = Sqrt(W*H/n)
```

and find exact value with linear or binary search

Comment: Linear search seems slow. Is there a better second approximation?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak But binary search is fast